# Splitting a string in arduino from computer

Tags: arduino-nano, serial-data

I am having an issue splitting an incoming string from a computer program to arduino. 
The incoming format is as follows:
123.456,987.654 \r\n

The comma separates the two values.
code is this(edit to add code most likely too many variables):

```
char c;
String com;
String targetstr;
String actualstr;
bool newdata = true;
float target =1;
float actual = 5;
float diff;
int pwm = 0;
float firstup = 2.75;
float firstdown = 2.25;
float intensifier = 5;
unsigned long lasttime = 0;
unsigned long currenttime = 0;
int watchdog = 1000;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(19200);
dac.begin(0x60);
}



void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
currenttime = millis();

while(Serial.available()>0&&newdata == true){
  c = Serial.read();
// switched to '\r' from '\n' for testing.
  if(c == 0x0D){}

  if(c ==0x0A){
  targetstr = getValue(com,0x2C,0);
  //targetstr = com.substring(0,com.indexOf(0x2C));
  target = targetstr.toFloat();
  actualstr = getValue(com,0x2C,1);
  //actualstr = com.substring(com.indexOf(0x2C)+1);
  actual = actualstr.toFloat();
  com = "";//reset string
  diff = actual - target;
  newdata = false; //reset flag
  lasttime = currenttime;
  //Serial.print("Diff = ");
  //Serial.println(diff);
  Serial.print("Tgt ");
  Serial.print(targetstr);
  Serial.print(" Act ");
  Serial.println(actualstr); 
  }
  else{
    com += c;
  }
```

The getValue is an example that I found on stack exchange

```
String getValue(String data, char separator, int index)
{
    int found = 0;
    int strIndex[] = { 0, -1 };
    int maxIndex = data.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex && found <= index; i++) {
        if (data.charAt(i) == separator || i == maxIndex) {
            found++;
            strIndex[0] = strIndex[1] + 1;
            strIndex[1] = (i == maxIndex) ? i+1 : i;
        }
    }
    return found > index ? data.substring(strIndex[0], strIndex[1]) : "";
}
```

So I have attempted two different ways to make this work. If I use the arduino serial monitor the code executes perfectly, but if I use the computer program it will not split the values.

In a serial monitor this is the sent code to the arduino via serial monitor(hex and ascii)

31 32 33 2E 34 35 36 2C 34 35 36 2E 31 32 33 0A   123.456,456.123.

and this is the arduino response
54 67 74 20 31 32 33 2E 34 35 36 20 41 63 74 20 34 35 36 2E 31 32 33 0D 0A                         Tgt 123.456 Act 456.123..

And this is code sent from the computer program to arduino:

31 36 31 2E 39 35 32 2C 31 35 30 2E 38 30 30 0D 0A    161.952,150.800..

arduino response:

54 67 74 20 2E 39 35 32 2C 31 35 30 2E 38 30 30 0D 20 41 63 74 20 0D 0A                   Tgt 161.952,150.800. Act ..

I am not sure of the reason of not splitting, I have tried ascii and hex in the code for the comma, as well as two methods of actually splitting.

What are some other things I can try?

Comment: Show the rest of the code.  Are you trying to do all of this with the String class?  This would be simpler with the data in a char array.  If c was a pointer to the char you're on then you could use atof on that and get a float, then find the comma and use atof again.  You're about to ask me for an example or something and that's not really possible without knowing what else you got going on here.

Comment: I was trying to minimize the code but keep it relevant. c is a char that gets wrapped into a string 'com'.. here is everything else in that part of the code.

Comment: Why would you "wrap" a char array into a String?  Just use the char array.

Comment: One problem that you have is that you start trying to extract the string while you are still reading it in.  I'm not sure how that works at all...  Is there an end marker to this packet?  Could you read to 7 char after the comma or something?  Either way, you need to read in the whole string before you start trying to convert it.  You can't convert what you haven't received yet.  If c==Ox0A where you start trying to convert that string, the actual first digit is still sitting in the buffer waiting to be read.

Comment: I tested your sketch with the data sent by your PC program, and it works as expected. Note, however, that since the string you send ends with `\r\n`, and you read up to the `\n`, the response of the Arduino ends in `\r\r\n`. You may want to replace `if (c == 0x0A)` by `if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')`. Note also that you can write `','`, `'\r'` and `'\n'` instead of `0x2C`, `0x0D` and `0x0A` respectively, and that would make the code easier to understand.

Comment: The reason I had them in hex was to test.. originally I had it as '\n' and ','  the \n at the end is the end marker

Comment: Do you have the code for the PC app? Did you write it? If so, what language was it written in?

Comment: I cannot comment on the pc app... I can sure ask though... im curious as to why it would matter